# Android app build in c# crashes on real device, but works on emulator

Tags: c#, android, crash

I have build an android app. My application works on the emulator, but when i export the .apk file, and test it on a real device, it just crashes instantly.

I already tried unchecking fast deployment, and shared runtime. I already checked the internet permission because i have a webview. The device that I'm using is android 5.0 and the app supports that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug the app in your device and check the log. It will be help you to find out the actual issue.
You said in your app you are using images so it may be crashes due to memory out of exception.